# Python 2.7 - can no longer start up

Tags: python-2.7, openshift

I restarted my app and it didn't come back up with the error:

```
httpd: Syntax error in -C/-c directive: Syntax error on line 1 of 
/var/lib/openshift/#######/python/etc/conf.d/wsgi.conf: Cannot load
/var/lib/openshift/#######/python/modules/python27-mod_wsgi.so into server: 
/var/lib/openshift/#######/python/modules/python27-mod_wsgi.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I changed nothing, not sure what to do.

Comment: Can't even spin up a new application with 2.7....

Comment: I see the same error - restarting an existing app fails.  It appears python/modules/python27-mod_wsgi.so no longer exists - I'm pretty sure this is supposed to come from Apache.

Comment: Seems their 2.7 cartridge is completely broken on their end.

Comment: It was working last night, but I've had no luck all day today.  Not sure how to report the error on their site.

Comment: I finally found, https://developers.openshift.com/contact.html and I reported it as a service interruption. I also hit up @openshift on Twitter.

Comment: Same problem here... :(

Comment: They got back to me this morning, they are now aware of the issue and are working on it. https://status.openshift.com

Comment: And they just fixed it 